# Can you help me to find out this question (Top 10 movie making country's video length mean) from netfix dataset

Tags: python-2.7, dataset, data-science, data-analysis, netflix

```
df_movies = df[df['type'] == 'Movie']

# top 10 movie making country

df_movies['country'].value_counts().index[:10] 

# movie duration mean for each country

df_movies.groupby(['minute']).mean()
```

I'm learning python in Jupyter notebook. I can't sort

> "Top 10 movie making country's video length mean"

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: So in other words, you are looking to find the **mean video duration** for **each** of the **top 10** movie-making countries.

Comment: also could you please provide the head of the dataframe:  i.e.  `df_movies.head()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the [same dataset](https://%27https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nataliafonseca/netflix-data-analysis/main/datasets/netflix_data.csv%27) that I used, this is the way I would do it:

#### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nataliafonseca/netflix-data-analysis/main/datasets/netflix_data.csv')

# Select only the movies
df_movies = df[df['type'] == 'Movie']

# top 10 movie making countries
top_10_countries = list(df_movies['country'].value_counts().index[:10])
print("Top10 Countries:", top_10_countries)


# movie duration mean for each country
avg_duration = df_movies[df_movies.country.isin(top_10_countries)].groupby('country')['duration']\
                                                                  .mean().reset_index()\
                                                                  .sort_values(by=['duration'])
print(avg_duration)
```

#### Output:

```
Top10 Countries: ['United States', 'India', 'United Kingdom', 'Canada', 'France', 'Spain', 'Egypt', 'Mexico', 'Turkey', 'Japan']

          country    duration
0          Canada   86.748571
5          Mexico   88.556962
9   United States   90.689048
8  United Kingdom   94.152493
4           Japan   95.360000
2          France   96.408759
6           Spain  102.016807
7          Turkey  107.538462
1           Egypt  109.548387
3           India  126.922990
```